# Using Youtube Iframe API, how do I resume video after I pause?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

**Use Case**

I have a series of buttons that when clicked, will pass a video ID value to my player and play the video from the start. It makes sense (from a usability standpoint) that if the user clicks on the same button while the video is playing, the video will pause. And if the button is clicked while the video is PAUSED, the video will resume at the same time as when it was paused.

**Sample jQuery**

```
    var $el = $('.video-button');
    $el.click(function(e) {
        if($el.hasClass('video-playing')) {
            myPlayer.pauseVideo();
        }
        else if($el.hasClass('video-paused')) {
            /* myPlayer.resumeVideo(); */
        }
        else                            
            myPlayer.playVideo();
    });
```

The question is, how do I resume the video after its been paused? The `playVideo` player function always seems to play a video from the beginning. I do not see a way to pass in a time value, ie `playVideo(145)` to  play the video starting at the 2:25 mark.

Is it possible to play a video starting at a specified time?

**Reference**
 [Youtube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls)

Comment: myPlayer.playVideo(); should play from the current position. Have you tested this and it is not working?

Comment: Yes, calling playVideo() after pauseVideo() restarts the video from the beginning. Perhaps I am re-initiating the video by accident?? I will investigate that. Thank you for confirming the default expected behavior.

Comment: @JeffWilkerson You should please update your post with the results that you achieved.